# Clicking "Trust Project" in PyCharm doesn't remove the notification

Tags: python, directory, pycharm

Whenever I open a project, it shows this notification:

[image]

And when I click trust project it doesn't do anything. This started happening ever since I changed the project folder location, is there any way to fix this?

Comment: The problem you are having if the answer didn't work only leaves you two choices: 1º either audit the [IDE configuration files](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html) manually - this one is very difficult because the contents of those configuration files aren't documented anywhere and you'll have to figure out what they mean by yourself. Or 2º make a new project (like I said in the comments below) and start over - this option should have you working within a few minutes.

Comment: The way you asked the question also doesn't allow to answer much beyond option 2 (starting over) because you didn't include the configuration files in the question and there's no way for users answering to guess what's in them, plus the configuration files can get very complex depending on project specifics.

Comment: that works, but whenever i make a NEW project it shows the same thing even if i add the folder to "trusted locations"

Comment: If it worked the way for you to figure the difference is creating 2 projects that are exactly the same, one project having the problem and the other after it's solved. Then compare the files inside the `.idea` folder and check what the difference is (since the projects are the same having only that difference. - I know it takes some work creating the projects but it's the only way to figure out what's happening when using the GUI doesn't work.)

Comment: This question can't be answered beyond what I already did, because the question doesn't include specific information on the OS, user account and file permissions (besides any IDE specific settings) which are all variables to the problem you're describing.

Answer (score 0):

The IDE is saying the project is opened in [*Safe mode*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQF21.png) this is a feature of [PyCharm's project security](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/project-security.html). It's meant to prevent a user from inadvertently running executable code from unknown sources that might not be safe.

> This started happening ever since I changed the project folder location

To remove the notification configure the new directory as a [trusted location](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/project-security.html#trust_sources) by going to `Settings` `>` `Build, Execution, Deployment` `>` `Trusted locations` and adding the directory to the list.

Depending if your project runs [startup tasks](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/project-security.html#startup_tasks) you may have to go to `Settings` `>` `Tools` `>` `Startup tasks` to manually configure the tasks.

[image: screenshot of trusted locations in settings]

Comment: I did try that but it doesn't go away. Is there any other way to fix it?

Comment: @Flashsloth if you tried the option in this answer and it didn't work try creating the project from scratch. Delete the `.idea` folder in the project directory (make a back up before you do) and [create a new project from your source code](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/importing-project-from-existing-source-code.html#existing-sources) to get a fresh start. (When using the GUI settings doesn't work it means a path was broken in the `.idea` folder when you moved the project the IDE can't fix  - fixing it by manually editing files depends on project specifics, a fresh start is cleaner.)

Comment: @Flashsloth projects directories aren't supposed to be moved except if using the built-in [refactoring move](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/move-refactorings.html) to ensure all the project setting paths get updated with the move. Also make sure to [invalidate caches](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/invalidate-caches.html) as you go along.